# If a magnet were hypothetically traveling faster than the speed of light, then how would that affect its magnetic field?

Tags: magnetic-fields, speed-of-light, big-bang

If a magnet were somehow traveling faster than the speed of light through perhaps starting with that initial velocity during the big bang or perhaps a alcubierre drive then how would this effect the magnetic field.

Comment: I echo Kyle Kanos in this comment: how can you use the laws  of physics to describe a situation which breaks the same laws of physics.?

Comment: It might be interesting, and more meaningful, to ask about a magnet traveling faster than the speed of light *in some medium*. This might have an effect similar to cherenkov radiation from charged particles: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherenkov_radiation